# Custom function getting data from API not updating

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a custom function that get data from an API and it works. The problem is that the data it gets changes within minutes, but the cell where I call the formula doesn't update. If I recalculate it (pressing enter) it doesn't update either. I have to delete the formula from the cell and re-enter it to get the data updated. I guess the code isn't running again as the google sheet sees that nothing in the workbook has changed.

How can I make it to update each 5 minutes for example?

Comment: The custom function called in the cell does not update well. I would say use a timedriven trigger that gets the data and then uses getRange().setValue()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So let us assume that you have a function named getData() that returns the data.

Instead of returning the data,  you could make the function insert the data to a specific cell calling

```
SpreadsheetApp.GetActiveSpreadsheet.GetActiveSheet().GetRange(row, col).setValue(data);
```

Now you could create a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#managing_triggers_programmatically) that calls the function every five minutes. One example is doing it programmatically like so:

```
function createTimeDrivenTriggers() {
 // Trigger every 5 minutes.
ScriptApp.newTrigger('getData')
 .timeBased()
 .everyMinutes(5)
 .create();
```

Remember to execute the triggerbuilder from the code editor.

Hope this was clear enough and helped at all. I'll proofread and test the exact formatting once I get to a computer.